# Sencha ExtJS Run Application

Tags: extjs

I did one ExtJS application on one PC and I want it to continue developing on another one. I copied the folders, initialized the `workspace.json` and ran `sencha app build`. After `sencha app watch` command I don't get any errors. However there is nothing on the screen and I get 404 messages for the JavaScript files even though they are existing in specified folders.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Btw It is Sencha ExtJS 6 version.

Answer (score 2):

For the description of the image, the **ext folder is missing**.

It is common to give this error when you do not have ext folder on the root application folder.